# $window.scrollTo scrolls to an incorrect div by ID

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, scroll

I want to scroll to an element `div2` by id and it sort of works. The only issue is it scrolls to the very top instead of `div2`.

This plunker shows how it works at the moment. Not sure what I'm doing wrong as I've specified the x and y axis correctly.

http://next.plnkr.co/edit/nYlZEVKrRSMfACBy

Comment: What's wrong with the question that it's got downvoted? I've looked at documentation of $window.scrollTo. Looks correct to me. I've even provided a plunker... Is it unclear?

Comment: I did not downvote, _but_ I'm guessing the reason is this: A good question on SO includes the relevant code _in the question_, **not** just a link to plunker / jsfiddle / etc.  For more info, [see this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code)

Comment: Doesn't a plunker show what the problem is in a more interactive way? Copying and pasting my code would just be a block of text in the post while plunker can be run and debugged.

Comment: Did you read the [link I added](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code)?   It explains why much better than I can in this comment, BUT, the sum-up from that post is: **It's allowed, but your post should hold up without the link**  - FURTHER, you can actually create a runnable snippet right in your question, which is optimal: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 0):

Got it working, replace:

```
$window.scrollTo(0, angular.element(document.getElementById('div2')).offsetTop);
```

with 
:

```
$window.scrollTo(0, document.getElementById('div2').offsetTop);
```